# How do you easily delete a Byte Order Mark (BOM) from a .java file or other types of file?

Tags: java, byte-order-mark

I kept having compile errors on my Continuous Integration & Deployment system.

After some research I found that it was a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of a .java file that was causing the error.

What is the easiest way to remove the BOM from the file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a very generally applicable answer and looks a lot like advertising for a specific product.

Comment: @Kayaman It's not advertising! It's an easy way to remove a BOM from a file. I found it the easiest way to remove a BOM from a file. Look at my other posts. I don't answer my own questions often, but thought this would be helpful to others.

Comment: @Kayaman additionally, p4merge is completely free, nor do I work for anyone affiliated with that company.

Comment: Nevertheless you didn't ask a very good question and you didn't give a very good answer, from StackOverflow guidelines point of view.

Comment: Indeed, "the best" (easiest even) questions no good for SO. And there are many ways to achieve this, like http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-remove-bom-from-utf-8 or http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php#remove - essentially either any editor that fails to decode utf and displays the BOM (you can simply remove the cryptic characters), or you have a (typically text editor) tool that does understand them but allows you to save with in a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for various solutions (such as VI, VIM, and scripts), but in the end the easiest solution was to utilize p4merge, which allows you to view the BOM and simply delete it.

You can get p4merge [here](https://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools) for free.

I'm not affiliated with p4merge in anyway, but I do use it and find it useful as a diff/merge tool.